# How to post a body correctly in Postman

Tags: node.js, api, post, request, postman

I try to make a post request to an api but, api returns error. Although I thought about it for a long time, I could not find the cause of the error.
I think the error is due to not creating the body correctly because when I send empty array as items array the code works.

API DOCUMENTATION:

[image: api request img]

Here is my request:

```
module.exports.createOrder = (token, paymentId, items, callback) => {
    const url = urlBase;
    request(
        {
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            json: true,
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            body: {
                secretKey: `${secretKey}`,
                paymentId: paymentId,
                items: items,
            },
        },
        (error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                Sentry.captureException(error);
                callback(errMessage, undefined);
            } else {
                const data = response.body;
                callback(undefined, data);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Here is test values:

```
const testToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYyM2RmYjg4NDA4M2IwMDAyNDNjYzRhNyIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODIyOTI1NywiZXhwIjoxNjQ4MzE1NjU3fQ.9fgR3ei81vsHVMhSi8VwEyE2WMgFIMthm0PF9_zrqjw"

const paymentId = "pi_1Dq2f62eZvKYlo2Cy1moIb0G"

const variant = {
    variations_values: {
        color:'Black',
        size:'42'
    },
    price:495,
    product_id: "883360511078"

}
const productId = "82936941"
const quantity = 1

const item = {
    variant:variant,
    productId:productId,
    quantity:quantity
}

let items = [item]

orderRequests.createOrder(testToken, paymentId, items, (err, data) => {
    if(data){
        console.log(data)
    } else{
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

I get internal server error as a response when I post these test values, but If I post an empty array as items, api does not return internal server error. What is the problem, any help?

Internal Server Error Response when I send an array with post body:

[image: error response img]

Expected request when I send an empty array with post body:

[image: emty error response img]

Comment: Why you need to inject productId and quantity into JSON body "item" again ?. because i saw it already mention in "variant". Not sure if it's help you. But you should try to throw the stack trace to check what's going on (If you are the one who implement this)

Comment: I inject them into item object because these two ids are different, productId is the main product id and product_id is the id of the variant and I need both of them to make a request. Also, I make a request to external API so I get an HTML page as an error from API don't know what the stack trace is.

Comment: I have added server's responses.

Comment: Are you using any framework(angular, react, vue) for frontend?

Comment: I use ejs with express on the frontend.